# perlのmapについて

Tags: perl

```
my @old = qw( 12 34abc56def 999 );
my @new  = map { /([a-z]+)/ } @old;
for my $n ( @new ){ print "[$n]\n"; }
print scalar @new,"\n";
```

上記コードの出力は、以下を期待していたのですが、

```
[]
[abc]
[]
3
```

実行してみると、

```
[abc]
1
```

となります。
どうしてこのような出力になるのか理解できません。
（mapの使い方が間違っている？）
どなたか、解説していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば、`my @new = map { local($_) = /([a-z]+)/ } @old;` と書き換えて、Data::Dumper で実行結果を確認すると(`print Dumper \@new;`)、`$VAR1 = [undef, 'abc', undef ];` となります。指定した正規表現にマッチしない場合には空文字列が返却される、という事ではない模様ですので、`my @new = map { /([a-z]+)/ ? $& : ""} @old;` とすれば期待通りの結果を得ることができます。詳しいことは分かりませんが、`print Dumper ("abc" =~ /([a-z]+)/);` と `print Dumper ("34" =~ /([a-z]+)/);` の表示結果を比較してみると、どうやら正規表現によるマッチングで、マッチしない場合には値を戻さない様に見えます(scalar 値に変換されない場合)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。正規表現にマッチしたものだけ返すのが仕様のようですね。(Effective Perl second edition  p.71にそれらしきことが書かれていました。)